# Is it possible to trigger two click events consecutively in one function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, click

On a certain event, I want to trigger a click event that loads a tab and then trigger another click event on a button on the tab consecutively.

Is it possible to trigger two click events in sequence? When I try doing so, the second one doesn't work.

Comment: wait for the tab to load. trigger event in callback of first

Comment: Dont forget to use jquery `.on()` method to trigger click events.

Comment: so you want to click once and trigger 2 events, in a single click?

Comment: both clicks should work independently in normal scenario, i.e. clicking on 1st should open the tab and clicking on second should fetch some results.

Comment: but in some other scenario. i want to open the tab with the fetched results. for that i want to trigger the two clicks in sequence. i dont want to bind both the clicks.

Answer (score 4):

`Yes` you can by using **[trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger)** like,

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('#tab,#button2').trigger('click');// trigger click of two elements
    // $('#tab,#button2').click();// use click() directly
});
```

Comment: `.trigger('click')` and `.click()` are equivalent, FYI.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    // do something here
});

$('#button2').click(function() {
    // do something else here

    // then simulate clicking the other thing:
    $('#button1').click();
});
```

Comment: thanks.. but i wanted to get both the click events called on some other event. i dont want to bind both clicks together each time. both clicks should function separately in normal scenario.

Comment: The point is, you can call `$('#button1').click();` and `$('#button2').click();` at any time and from anywhere.